# iPhone Smart App Banners - openUrl not called

Tags: ios, banner, openurl

Hey stackoverflow fellows, 
 

 
I recently tried to implement the Smart App Banners from Apple. 
 
They work but, I'm not able the get app-argument data in my App. 
 
The App runs on iOS 5, 6, & 7 but I tried iOS 6 & 7 only, too. 

 
Here's my code for the Banner:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=688798564, app-argument=http://app.heimwerker.de/2" />
```

This is my implementation:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
NSLog(@"URL: %@",url.absoluteString);

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
ReadViewController *dest = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReadVC"];
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
dest.uid = [format numberFromString: url.absoluteString];
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Smart App" message:url.absoluteString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];


return YES;
```

}

This method is never called. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reported iOS7 bug. Have a look [at the open bug report](https://devforums.apple.com/message/897373#897373)
It should work on iOS6 though

Comment: Fixed in 7.1, but per the open bug report, there is a related ticket that was opened as well: http://openradar.appspot.com/15776183

Comment: @JasonShah Are you sure it is fixed in 7.1? Still can't get it to work (including 7.1.2).